# Deploying my Symfony App, Having 404 css releated errors

Tags: symfony

Im moving to production environment, since my dev and production server are the same i think the passage from one environment to the other is just using app.php instead of app-dev.php. Doing so im getting some 404 errors related to css files, so i believe since css is handle by assectic this problem might be related with cache right? But I have no idea of how to handle this.

I have ssh access to my server, but a solution using just ftp will be also good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run the command dumping your asset files:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment

If you have used the `prod` environnement before, you probably want to clear the cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Or you can simply delete everything inside the `app/cache` folder if you want to only use your FTP client.

Comment: Now im getting a HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) when i try to access the app.php

Comment: [2013-02-24 17:08:03] request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /css/a6715c3_fonts_1.css" (uncaught exception) at /var/www/vhosts/punctis.com/httpdocs/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 5735 [] []

Comment: Done!, guess what, a permissions issue with the folders, i had a similar problem in dev. Well now i have another issue :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056731/symfony2-routing-in-production-environment-sends-me-to-dev-environment